# my obj is not centered

Tags: vertices

i've been trying to make some cc for the sims, but when i export my obj from marvelous designer to blender, the obj like this
[image: the obj appears on the floor, and it's not centered]

i tried to make it fit the model manual but i just can't, i need it to go directly to the model and not move

Comment: Hi maria, welcome to Blender.SE. Could you please edit your post and explain what ***the object like this*** means! Have you looked at the transformations of all your objects/armatures?

Comment: It's probably due to Blender using Z as up in the coordinate system and the export to obj using Marvelous Designers coordinate system

Answer (score 1):

The object looks like a shirt. It has it origin centered, I can tell from looking at the transforms. Technically the object is centered. The problem is that the rotations aren't matching, Blender using the Z axis up, and marvelous designer apparently uses the Y axis as up. If you rotate the object on the X axis 90  or -90 degrees it should line up.